# Where can I post Microsoft Excel 2016 related questions?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I have a problem filtering rows in Microsoft Excel 2016. Where can I post these types of questions?

Comment: That depends on your question. Is it a "Programming" question? Or is it more of a "how to use Excel"?

Comment: @Glorfindel you are right (retracted my dupe vote). Thanks for heads up - I frequently forget that dupe target doesn't cover stuff like that

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised at first as well that SU/SF weren't covered.

Answer (score 8):

Try [Super User](http://superuser.com). They have a lot of questions about [Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) – chances are your question is already covered.

Unless your question involves heavily use of VBA, it will be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ Glorifindel great, thanks man. no it's just about filtering rows

Comment: @RaJ then Super User is definitely the place to be.